# Visual Studio Team Services npm git private package

Tags: git, npm, azure-devops

I'm using Visual Studio Team Services and I have build defined which is running `npm install`. `npm` is downloading package via `git+ssh`. This repo is my second repository in my project but agent don't have assess rights to that second repository.

Project

- MainApp (build runs here and tries to download SecondRepo)
- SecondRepo (is `npm` dependency to MainApp)

What is the solution to this problem? I thought that agent would have rights to whole project not only one repository within project.

Comment: I'll have to check how to make it working with VSTS. Thanks for pointing me to that question.

Comment: Could you restore/install that package by running npm command manually on your local machine?

Comment: Yes because I have access to this repo. It's strange that agent have troubles with access since this is the same project.

Comment: From what I understand agent should have access via authorization scope in options but both options don't work

Comment: What's the result after you trying Luca's solution?

Comment: I have troubles with setting this up with VSTS. I'll let you know in case I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Team Services require to specify `npm` package via `git+https`.

```
{
  "package": "git+https://{your_email}:{your_private_access_token}@{team}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_git/{repo}#{commit_hash}"
}
```

Comment: What, why? Feels like it's a bit too much.. How does this work for every individual developer that requires that package? ::/

Comment: We used one of ours account. It's not perfect but we were small team. I'm not working on project using this right now so maybe something changed and this is no longer an issue.

Comment: How does that work with licensing though? As far as I know it's not really allowed to let multiple people use the same account.

Comment: We were using multiple accounts for the day-to-day work. We were sharing only one account to download one project dependency. Because of the problem above.